# Custom DateTime formatting in c#

Tags: c#, string, datetime, string-formatting, datetime-format

I have a variable which is printed out using the following string format:

```
var printThis = String.Format("{0:d}, {0:T}", dateAndTimeVar);
```

Now I have a problem; I need '{0:T}' to display something like '--.--.--' when I have not set any time to the 'dateAndTimeVar'. This seems not supported using the regular DateTime type (showing '00.00.00' by default if there is no time set).

I can change the 'dateAndTimeVar' variable to anything (including other types), but the string formatting must remain the same.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: What is your desired string for `DateTime.Today`?

Comment: I want it to display e.g. "1919,10,10 --.--.--" when there is no time and "1919,10,10, 12.43.10" when time is present.

Comment: Is only possible to do something like if the whole variable is null or if you separate the time of day. The time "00:00:00" is a valid time (midnight), so the compiler does not interpret as null. If you separate the time of day you can make a check when dealings in nil or is 00:00:00 and write the way you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to create your own IFormatProvider and pass it into the String.Format method like this

```
String.Format(new MyFormatProvider(), "{0:d}, {0:T}", dateAndTimeVar);
```

The FormatProvider would then do a pass-through on all formats except T, where you would have your logic for outputting either the native T format for DateTime or --.--.-- if the Time-part of DateTime is 00:00:00.

Read about IFormatProvider on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx)

Comment: IFormatProvider is powerful, but way too often overlooked aspect of format strings. People tend to thing that the provided formats are fixed and written in stone, which is definitively not the case.

Answer (score 1):

This a list of date time patterns you can use

[DateTime.ToString() Patterns | GeekZilla](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)

Cheers

Comment: I cannot change the pattern unfortunately. Only the in-variable.

Comment: Can you add what you want printThis variable to look like, in full?

Comment: @drbaltar: So you cannot change the format to get the corrrect format but you want to modify the variable instead? That sounds really weird.

Comment: Well I guess I can change the format somewhat, but the only output change should be that --.--.-- should be displayed when there is no time.

Comment: @TimSchmelter what is so weird about that? Maybe in the real-world code, the format string comes from a compiled resource-string maintained by some UI department 24223 miles away.

Comment: @PauliØsterø: Possibly, maybe it sounds just weird for me without details. Sometimes people refactor code around instead of fixing the core problem directly.

Comment: @PauliØsterø: That is actually exactly the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this:

```
var printThis = String.Format("{0:d}, {0:T}", dateAndTimeVar)
                      .Replace("00:00:00", "--.--.--");
```

Comment: String.Format("{0:d}, {0:T}", dateAndTime.GetValue()); yields 1919,10,10, 1919,10,10, 1919,10,10, 1919,10,10 :\

Comment: Ok modified to pass in the format string as a parameter. You can just print out the return value.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can't print this directly -the value must go through a String.Format("{0:d}, {0:T}", theValue);

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check if the `DateTime` contains a time:

```
String printThis = dateAndTimeVar.Date == dateAndTimeVar ?  
    String.Format("{0:d}, --.--.--", dateAndTimeVar) : 
    String.Format("{0:d}, {0:T}", dateAndTimeVar);
```

Comment: the OP specifically mentioned that the Format String cannot be changed

Comment: @PauliØsterø: He [commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645035/custom-datetime-formatting-in-c-sharp/13645097#comment18720402_13645097): _"Well I guess I can change the format somewhat, but the only output change should be that --.--.-- should be displayed when there is no time."_

Comment: true, but summing up on the total amount of times mentioned that it cannot be changed, versus that it "maybe" can be changed, i would assume that the safest bet is that its pretty fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and sorry for being unclear in the question. I may change the format string itself, not immediate logic around it unfortunately.

Comment: @drbaltar: That makes it even more unclear. You can change the format string(as in my answer suggested) but you cannot change the logic around? What's the logic around, is it changed by  my code?

Comment: The format string comes from a resource file, this I can change.